# How to undo a user delete from Firebase dashboard?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I created an app with login through phone number and OTP, I logged in to the app with my phone number then I deleted the number(user) from firebase auth users. Now I'm unable to log in back with that number, after deleting the account and logging in again it should create the account with a new Uid but it's not logging in or sending me an OTP through SMS. There's a way by putting that number in testing mode but I don't want that. Is there any way to get the deleted user log back in the app?

Answer (score 3):

> How to undo a user delete from the Firebase dashboard?

There is no way you can do that. If you have deleted a user directly from the Firebase Console, there is no way you can recover it.

Please also note that when you delete an account that way, it doesn't mean that the current session automatically expires for that account. That session will remain active for about an hour. After that, you can sign in again with the same number.

Comment: Hey Nimesh. Can I help you with other information?